# Less nested rules get parent properties

Tags: css, less

Hello I am wondering is it possible to do something like this in less. I have this css:

```
.parent{display: block; color: red; border: yellow 1px solid;}
.parent a, .parent a.special-link{color: blue; border-color: green;}
```

I would write it in less like this:

```
.parent{
    display: block; 
    color: red; 
    border: yellow 1px solid;

    a, a.special-link{
        color: blue; border-color: green;
    }
}
```

And rules are ok but what if in further developing I have to add something to :hover but only for it eg. padding: 20px; What is the best way to do this? My first thought is that if there is some kind of workaround/hack/selector that allows to inherit all properties of parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt I clearly understand your exact needs (":hover" of what? "only" for what "it"?)
But in general it usually goes like this:

```
.parent {
    display: block;
    color:   red;
    border:  yellow 1px solid;

    a {
        // <a> properties:
        // ...

        &, &.special-link {
            // <a> and <a.special-link> properties:
            // ...
            color:        blue;
            border-color: green;
        }

        &.special-link {
            // <a.special-link> properties:
            // ...
        }

        &:hover {
            // <a:hover> properties:
            // ...
        }

        /// etc. etc. etc.
    }
}
```